# Chart.js: tooltip callbacks title

Tags: chart.js

Chart.js (tried v 4.4.0, also 3.7.1) and chartjs-plugin-datalabels (2.2.0, 2.0.0).
I’m trying to use the tooltip callbacks title as … (xValuesLabel is a special label array)

```
title: function(tooltipItem) {return xValuesLabel[tooltipItem.dataIndex]}
```

… it does not show the title using 3.7.1, no error, using 4.4.0 it does show the x-axis actual label, not from array xValuesLabel.
When I’m using …

```
title: function(tooltipItems) {return xValuesLabel[tooltipItems[0].dataIndex]}
```

… it does show the title from array xValuesLabel for a while, after moving around on the chart from title to title error appear (in the inspecting area) and very often chart just hangs. The same happens when I’m using “context[0]”, “items[0]” … error “Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'dataIndex')”.
But ...

```
beforeLabel: function(tooltipItem) {return xValuesLabel[tooltipItem.dataIndex]}
```

... does work as expected.
Using ...

```
title: function(tooltipItem) {return xValuesLabel[0]}
```

... does work, meaning it does bring first value from array xValuesLabel, just trying, of course there is needed variable dataIndex etc.

Probably I missed something?

What interesting, when dataset type is 'line' and 'title' is used using '[0]' ('tooltipItem[0].dataIndex' or 'tooltipItems[0].dataIndex' or 'context[0].dataIndex' etc.) graph hangs almost immediately when tooltips touched, but using 'bar' not so often, but still sometimes. Have never seen such a hanging before when used 'beforeLabel' avoiding using index in 'title'.

So, conclusion at this moment: when trying to customize tooltip callbacks title property then … chart does hang, more often when dataset type ‘line’ is used, less when ‘bar’. Odd. But, as I said, probably is there something I’m doing wrongly.

More thanks, Alar.